# Stage Picklist on Opportunity Not Shown by LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, picklist, error, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I am trying to show stage picklist values of opportunity object through lwc but iit shows error
Invalid reference Opportunity.Stage of type sobjectField in file lwcPicklistOppor.js

here is my code

```
<template>
    <div class="side-box">
        <template if:true={StageValues.data}>
           
            <lightning-combobox value={value} label="Opportunity Stage" onchange={handleChange} options={stageValues.data.values}
                name="progress"> </lightning-combobox>
            </template>

    </div>

    
</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement,wire } from 'lwc';
import OPPORTUNITY_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoapi';
import Stage from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Stage';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoapi';

export default class LwcPicklistOppor extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName : Opportunity_OBJECT})
    opportunityinfo;
    @wire(getPicklistValues,
        {
            recordTypeId: '$opportunityinfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId',
            fieldApiName: Stage
        }
    )
    StageValues;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Opportunity Stage field is actually called `StageName`:

```
import Stage from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.StageName';
```

You can, and should, check the documentation (e.g. [Opportunity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm)) and/or Setup in your org to find a field's name.

Comment: Thank You ...it removes the error but now when i deploy this to org it gives unknown Exception

Comment: @ShivaniTanwar Not sure what to say about that. You may need to use a reactive variable that gets set by the getObjectInfo call.

Comment: Could you please show me how can i do this?

Comment: @ShivaniTanwar https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/255959/2984