# Execute one of Wire methods before other LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, wire

I have five wire methods in my LWC.
And I want to execute one of them at first.
And only if this one is successfful - execute others.

**Is there any way to tell my LWC  Which wire method I want to execute as the first ?**

Here some of my wire methods  :

```
@wire(isUserLicenced, {userId : USER_ID})  // this one should be the first
isUserLicencedMethod({error,data}) {
    if (error) {
       console.error(error); 
    } else if (data) {
        console.log('isUserSetupLicenced'); 
    }
}

@wire(getPermissions)
getPermissionsData({ data, error }) {
    if(data) {
        console.log('getCustomPermissionsMapData'); 
    } else if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

@wire(getCashDrawerOpenReasons)
setCashDrawerOpenReasons({error,data}) {
    if(data) {
        console.log('setCashDrawerOpenReasons'); 
    } else if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

I saw [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/255958/chain-wire-methods-together-in-lightning-web-components) , However it **did not help me**!

Maybe someone has already done something similar ?

**Any help will be appreciated.**
thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wire methods are all called *at once*, immediately after the first render cycle. You cannot control the order in which they will be called, nor can you prevent them from being called; wire methods are guaranteed to execute.

As such, you need [imperative Apex calls](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_call_imperative):

```
  permissionsData
  cashDrawerOpenReasons
  @wire(isUserLicenced, { userId: USER_ID }) // this one should be the first
  isUserLicencedMethod({ error, data }) {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } else if (data) {
      console.log("isUserSetupLicenced");
      Promise.all([getPermissions(), getCashDrawerOpenReasons()]).then(
        (results) =>
          ([this.permissionsData, this.cashDrawerOpenReasons] = results)
      );
    }
  }
```

If you need to periodically refresh this data (it doesn't seem like it, but I thought I'd mention it), write a separate method that you can call to update the properties on demand.

Comment: Ok, thank you.
I will go with your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can not prioritize wire methods in LWC (till date) but you can use the combination of wire and imperative to achieve what you're looking for.

Use 1 Wire method and add other as imperative Apex calls.
More from [here](https://www.mhamzas.com/blog/2019/06/25/apex-calling-methods-in-lightning-web-components/)

Comment: thank you. I appreciate your answer.